# Is there something like "Anchors" (javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics) in java.awt.Graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, anchor

Need to rewrite JavaME application for JavaSE. (source code is not mine)
There are "draw*" methods using anchors, but how can I implement this in awt?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what kind of anchors your are interested in. If your are wanna just use three lines do something like this

```
public void paintAnchor( Point start, Point end, Graphics g ) {
  g.drawLine( start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
  g.drawLine( end.x - ( end.x / 10 ), end.y - 5, end.x, end.y );
  g.drawLine( end.x - ( end.x / 10 ), end.y + 5, end.x, end.y );
}
```

this ist the simplest approach i can think about. And you will see it will only work good for a horizontal anchor. So what you have to do is, you have to implement it for different angles, maybe different thicknesses and for each quadrant of the coordinate system.

An alternative could be to select a specific font with anchors and just paint them. So it depends on what you trying to do.

sincerely

Comment: anchors i mean the position of drawn string\img\whatever relative to point (x,y). javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics allows these anchors like this:  g.drawString(str, x, y, Graphics.RIGHT | Graphics.BOTTOM). - this means that (x,y) will be bottom right of the string